# Blender 2.8 Won't Run

Tags: installation

I'm running a brand new installation of Windows 10 Pro on a Dell XPS 8930 on a 500 gb m2 drive. I install Blender 2.8 or 2.82a but when I run it it shows the command window briefly and then a blank window and then quits. I haven't tried earlier versions.

---

I reinstalled Windows 10 and now it works wonderfully.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: Hi, welcome! You could maybe try to start blender from the command line, to have more chances to keep some error messages appearing...

Comment: The instructions provided [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports/173685#173685) should help you resolve the issue.

Comment: When I try to run it on the command line I get an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION error.

Comment: I should also point out that before I installed the m2 drive and made it the boot drive Blender ran fine on this machine.  I installed the drive to speed up Blender's execution which was becoming very slow

Answer (score 0):

I found  solution.

@Carl
-check the driver-version of your graphicCard directly at the manufacturer's site. 
Surprisingly  he internal windows driverCheck via deviceManager lies saying all drivers are up2date!
-continue with a fresh installation of the latest blender
 ... worked for me.

Comment: I have dual video cards.  When I updated each of the cards drivers it only caused Blender to quit more quickly.  Now it's just a flash.